# Extracting value from field with logstash conf file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have a log something like:

> id:0422  time:[2013-11-19 02:34:58]   level:INFO  text:(Lorem Ipsum is
> simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry)
> params:query:google$some value$dummy data$lorem Ipsum

After processing with logstash I'm getting fields with values like:

```
ID=0422
Timestamp=[2013-11-19 02:34:58]
loglevel=INFO  
params=query:google$some value$dummy data$lorem Ipsum
text=(Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry)
```

Into elastic search first output.

&
`params=query:google$some value$dummy data$lorem Ipsum`    into a second elastic index.

I want to extract only `query:google` to be store into that second elastic index.
How can I achieve that??

Answer (score 0):

you can clone the event using the clone filter

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-clone.html

Just add a tag to it and use the in tags functionality to make sure you are only manipulating the event you want to manipulate and use it also to decide to which index you want to write to.

```
clone {
  clones => ["params"]
  add_tag => ["sendtoindex2"]
}
...
#use the structure below when you want to know which flow to take (you can also use not in [tags])
if ("sendtoindex2" in [tags]) {
  ...
else {
  ...
}
```

To make sure you only have the part you are interested in use the grok filter

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

For your example here it would be something like:

```
^%{DATA:name_of_variable_you_want_to_use}\$
```